# How can I create a virtually lower and letterboxed resolution?

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a screen which only accepts the 1920x1080 mode (others are garbled and adding custom modes does not work either). However, the screen has a centered viewable area of 1440x1080. That means the external screen crops the left and right.

I would like to make the resolution of that screen virtually smaller while keeping the same display mode, effectively adding letterboxes on the left and right. I have been trying some things with xrandr but I always ended up scaling the output which is not what I want.

[Example for the result I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJQIc.png)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 21.04

**tl;dr**: I would like to create a virtual screen of 1440x1080 and display it on an external display which is fixed to mode 1920x1080.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re running? This will make it more likely that you receive an actionable answer 

Comment: Could you check the image?  I only see a white rectangle, which is not really meaningfull.